# Can't display popup while using Fragment

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

I have problem when I use the popup menu in fragment

this is my popup menu function

```
public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_context_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }
```

how to solve this problems?

Comment: did you receive any error?

Comment: What do you pass as `View view`? The fragment or his parent activity?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to put proper `view` argument while using method `showPopupMenu(View view)` :

```
    public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view); //use getActivity() in fragment

        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard_context_menu, popup.getMenu()); //optimize code ;)
        popup.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Fragment` so you have to pass context from Activity which holding the `Fragment`. So you have to edit code `context` to `getActivity();`

```
public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_context_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

### or

You can edit `showPopupMenu` Method

```
public void showPopupMenu(Context context, View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_context_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

### Call the method

```
your_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//your_view can be Button, TextView, EditText etc   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupMenu(getActivity(),v);
        }
});
```